# Activate pref to hide macvim when last window closes, via vimrc or command line

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

MacVim has a preference item under "General > After last window closes" that gives the option to Hide MacVim. This returns focus to the terminal after the last MacVim window is closes via :q.

I'd like to add this preference to my dotfiles, either via an entry in my vimrc or via directly manipulating the OSX user preferences database via "defaults write org.vim.MacVim..."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help macvim-user-defaults` for a list of dictionary entries. The right one is not listed, though:

```
MMLastWindowClosedBehavior
```

Comment: Thanks. The complete line I ended up using is `defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMLastWindowClosedBehavior -int 1`.